# Application run on Azure AKS Kubernates can not be accessed from App Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-virtual-network, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I have configured two different applications ( SEQ and MockServer ) on Azure AKS service. They are both working correctly from internet but can not access them from Azure Web Service. It also can not be accessed from Azure CLI.
Below my

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mockserver-deployment
  labels:
    app: mockserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mockserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mockserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mockserver
        image: jamesdbloom/mockserver
        env:
        - name: LOG_LEVEL
          value: "INFO"        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-secret
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mockserver-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mockserver
  loadBalancerIP: 51.136.53.26
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  # from Poland
  - 62.87.152.154/32 
  - 83.30.150.205/32
  - 80.193.73.114/32
  - 195.191.163.0/24
  # from AppCenter test
  - 195.249.159.0/24
  - 195.0.0.0/8
  # from Marcin K home
  - 95.160.157.0/24
  - 93.105.0.0/16
  ports:
  - port: 1080
    targetPort: 1080
    name: mockserver
```

Comment: so ugh, where's the question? you didn't allow your IP address range - and it doesnt work. surprise?

Comment: Problem is that even I open it to whole internet , it is not possible to access from azure web service or CLI. How to allow web service to access that ?

Comment: thats obviously not true

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use VNET integration for your AppService (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) combined with an internal LoadBalancer-type Service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb). This way the communication between the app service and AKS will flow only via the internal VNET. Note that you can have *also* an external LB service like the one you already have; you can have multiple services serving traffic to the same set of pods.